# How to iterate over each item once within a list in f# functionally?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Hi i was wondering is there was a way to iterate over each item once within a list, in java i would use a for each loop to access each item within an arraylist, however i want to take a functional approach with f#. The best method i can think of would be to use the first item in the head of the list then delete it so the next item will be the head (then carry on until there is no more values left with the list). the only problem with that is i dont know how to implement it as i am still very new to this language. any help will be appreciated.

for convenience sake lets assume i have a list:

```
let mylist = ["hello";"bird";"dog";"cat";"snake"]
```

Comment: What are you wanting to do with each item in the list? Modify it? Do some no-op like printing it out?

Comment: i just want to print each item once. for example, displaying first element in mylist then do something else, then come back and print the second element in mylist.

Comment: It begs the question – where did [the language documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/lists), or [module documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.list-module-%5Bfsharp%5D), fail? What is your specific question after reading those?

Comment: it would probably be with recursion of lists, i can show every element with the list without a problem but i am having trouble showing only one at a time. after each loop i want to remove the head of the list so the next element is available until the list is empty

Comment: Note that "iterate" and "functional" are contradictory terms. If you want to "take functional approach", you have already failed when you started thinking about "iterating".

Comment: what method would you suggest?

Answer (score 24):

#### Idiomatic version

If you just want to do this in regular F# code, rather than for educational purposes, then the easiest option is to use `for`. This is not particularly functional, but since the task is imperative in its nature, this is the way to go:

```
for item in mylist do
  printfn "%s" item
```

#### Higher-order function

A bit more functionally-looking solution is to use higher-order function `List.iter`. This is useful as part of longer pipelines, but it illustrates some functional features, namely using functions as arguments:

```
mylist |> List.iter (fun item ->
  printfn "%s" item)
```

#### Recursive version

Finally, you can also do this using recursion and pattern matching on lists. This is essentially what `List.iter` does behind the scenes - rather than "deleting" the head, this decomposes the list into head and tail and then processes the tail recursively after printing the item in the head:

```
let rec iter items = 
  match items with
  | [] -> ()
  | head::tail -> 
     printfn "%s" head
     iter tail

iter mylist
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas, this is great, but what if i have maps within my lists (a scenario)? how can i use it for that?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing a concrete example - you can post it as a new question, but make sure to include the code you wrote so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903584/how-to-use-recursive-of-list-functionally here you go :)