# How to use recursive of list, functionally

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming

Say i have a list containing maps:

```
let mone = Map.ofList["1", "cat"; "2", "tiger"; "3", "lynx"]
let mtwo= Map.ofList["1", "dog"; "2", "wolf"; "3", "puppy"]
let mthree= Map.ofList["1", "bird"; "2", "chicken"; "3", "pigeon"]

let mlist = [mone; mtwo; mthree]
```

how can i use recursive to display one map at a time, rather then displaying all the maps? for example, displaying first element then ending iteration, to move onto something else, then displaying the second element etc.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Could you perhaps give an example of the kind of output you're looking for? There's probably a function in the standard F# `List` module that will help you do what you want, but it's hard to understand what you've written so far, so an extra example would help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: To get an answer, please add two things. 
(1) What results would you like to get?
(2) What code did you already write and where specifically are you stuck?